# VB for Excel on Mac, string functions len, left, right, mid

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Are the len, left, right and mid functions available for use in excel VBA on a mac? I am using Excel for Mac 2011.

I wish to be able to do some string manipulation in code but can't as these functions don't appear to work.

I am getting an error message that says the "user-defined type is not defined" when I call any of these functions. The code editor recognises the function name as it capitalises the first letter of each one so its strange that it is treating this as an user-defined function.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim str As String
    Dim strLength As Integer

    str = Target.Value 'get a string from the cell just updated

    strLength = Application.WorksheetFunction.Len(str)

    Worksheets(1).Range("a1") = strLength 'output the length of the string into cell A1

End Sub
```

I have search around the web and can't find an answer to this question. Just plenty examples of string manipulation in action.

Any help gratefully received.

Thanks, Mike

Comment: Did you try not using `Application.WorksheetFunction` and just using `Len` instead? See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213646 for specific code examples and more information.

Comment: Thanks Ken! I had tried that VLOOKUP and FIND but it didn't work without either Application or Application.WorksheetFunction, so I assumed these functions would be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just omit the `Application.WorksheetFunction` and use `Len` by itself.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim str As String
    Dim strLength As Integer

    str = Target.Value 
    strLength = Len(str)
    Worksheets(1).Range("a1") = strLength 
End Sub
```

While it's a little outdated (for Excel 2003), [this MS support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213646) might help; the VBA string functions haven't changed since then.